After keycloak login page "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '&iss'"
I have an angular application authenticating using keycloak, keycloak-angular and keycloak-js. It was working good but recently it started to throw below error on the console.
core.mjs:6484 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '&iss'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '&iss'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.mjs:2936:16)
    at router.mjs:2918:28
    at catchError.js:10:38
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:19:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:1)
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:64:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1213:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1167:1)
    at zone.js:1279:1
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25463:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:582:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:491:1)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1600:1)

And in the browser it shows below url and nothing else on the page. All network calls are success. And strangely if I connect the application with other instance of keycloak it works good. So does that mean some configuration is incorrect for keycloak, what that could be? I have compared the two instances and both looks same. There is nothing much that I can debug here, all library functions. Also I suspect something else is failing but that is not getting logged. Any leads would be helpful, thanks!
http://localhost:4200/#/&iss=https://keycloakhost/realms/myrealmname


Well the problem was keycloak application was upgraded to the newer version, but we continued with the older versions of the keycloak-js and keycloak-angular, after those are aligned with the required versions problem is solved.
